# Unable to save state for first click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

I'm building a react component where users can choose between options and once the user hits save after choosing, I'm saving the options in the state. However, it's not getting saved after the first click of saving (which is inside the modal). Once I close the modal and open again then the last chosen options are getting saved.

**Sample.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Modal from "./Modal";

class Sample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      usersUn: [
        { id: 1, name: "kepa" },
        { id: 2, name: "rudiger" },
        { id: 3, name: "alonso" },
        { id: 4, name: "Christensen" },
        { id: 7, name: "Kante" },
        { id: 8, name: "Barkley" },
        { id: 9, name: "Tammy" },
        { id: 10, name: "willian" },
        { id: 11, name: "pedro" },
        { id: 12, name: "Loftus-Cheek" },
        { id: 13, name: "Caballero" },
        { id: 15, name: "Zouma" },
        { id: 18, name: "Giroud" },
        { id: 19, name: "Mount" },
        { id: 20, name: "Hudson-Odoi" },
        { id: 22, name: "Pulisic" },
        { id: 23, name: "Batshuayi" },
        { id: 24, name: "James" },
        { id: 28, name: "azpilicueta" },
        { id: 29, name: "tomori" },
        { id: 33, name: "Emerson" }
      ],
      usersSel: [{ id: 17, name: "kovacic" }, { id: 5, name: "jorginho" }],
      isLoading: false,
      err: null
    };
  }

  save = (itemsLeft, itemsRight) => {
    this.setState({
      usersUn: itemsLeft,
      usersSel: itemsRight
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        usersUn={this.state.usersUn}
        usersSel={this.state.usersSel}
        loading={this.state.isLoading}
        err={this.state.err}
        title="Gimme a title"
        leftTitle="Squad"
        rightTitle="PL11"
        save={this.save}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Sample;
```

**Modal.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";

class Modal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      itemsLeft: this.props.usersUn,
      itemsRight: this.props.usersSel,
      selectedLeft: [],
      selectedRight: [],
      filterLeft: "",
      filterRight: ""
    };
  }

  openModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: false,
      itemsLeft: this.props.usersUn,
      itemsRight: this.props.usersSel
    });
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  selectLeft = id => {
    const selectedVal = this.state.itemsLeft.filter(user => user.id === id);
    // console.log(selectedVal);
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        selectedLeft: [...prevState.selectedLeft, ...selectedVal]
      };
    });
  };

  selectRight = id => {
    const selectedVal = this.state.itemsRight.filter(user => user.id === id);
    // console.log(selectedVal);
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        selectedRight: [...prevState.selectedRight, ...selectedVal]
      };
    });
  };

  moveAllRight = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        itemsLeft: [],
        itemsRight: [...prevState.itemsRight, ...prevState.itemsLeft]
      };
    });
  };

  moveRight = () => {
    const updatedItemsLeft = this.state.itemsLeft.filter(item => {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.state.selectedLeft.length; i++) {
        if (this.state.selectedLeft[i].id === item.id) return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
    const updatedItemsRight = [
      ...this.state.itemsRight,
      ...this.state.selectedLeft
    ];
    this.setState({
      itemsLeft: updatedItemsLeft,
      itemsRight: updatedItemsRight,
      selectedLeft: []
    });
  };

  moveLeft = () => {
    const updatedItemsRight = this.state.itemsRight.filter(item => {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.state.selectedRight.length; i++) {
        if (this.state.selectedRight[i].id === item.id) return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
    const itemsLeft = [...this.state.itemsLeft, ...this.state.selectedRight];
    this.setState({
      itemsLeft: itemsLeft,
      itemsRight: updatedItemsRight,
      selectedRight: []
    });
  };

  moveAllLeft = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        itemsRight: [],
        itemsLeft: [...prevState.itemsLeft, ...prevState.itemsRight]
      };
    });
  };

  saveList = () => {
    this.props.save(this.state.itemsLeft, this.state.itemsRight);
    this.closeModal();
  };

  filterItems = (items, filterTxt) => {
    return items.filter(item =>
      item.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterTxt.toLowerCase())
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { loading, err, title, leftTitle, rightTitle } = this.props;
    const { itemsLeft, itemsRight, filterLeft, filterRight } = this.state;

    const filteredDataL = this.filterItems(itemsLeft, filterLeft);
    const filteredDataR = this.filterItems(itemsRight, filterRight);

    if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    if (err) {
      return <div>{err}</div>;
    }

    return (
      <>
        <button className="button" onClick={this.openModal}>
          Open Modal
        </button>
        <Popup open={this.state.open} modal closeOnDocumentClick>
          <div className="modal__content">
            <div className="modal__header">
              <h4>{title}</h4>
              <button onClick={this.closeModal}>&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal__body">
              <div>
                <h4>
                  {leftTitle}
                  {`(${itemsLeft.length})`}
                </h4>
                <div>
                  <input
                    type="search"
                    name="filterLeft"
                    placeholder="search"
                    value={filterLeft}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="results">
                  {filteredDataL.map(user => {
                    return (
                      <div
                        className="list__item"
                        key={user.name}
                        onClick={() => this.selectLeft(user.id)}
                      >
                        {user.name}
                        {`(${user.id})`}
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="controls">
                <button onClick={this.moveAllRight}>&gt;&gt;</button>
                <button onClick={this.moveRight}>&gt;</button>
                <button onClick={this.moveLeft}>&lt;</button>
                <button onClick={this.moveAllLeft}>&lt;&lt;</button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h4>
                  {rightTitle}
                  {`(${itemsRight.length})`}
                </h4>
                <div>
                  <input
                    type="search"
                    placeholder="search"
                    name="filterRight"
                    value={filterRight}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="results">
                  {filteredDataR.map(user => {
                    return (
                      <div
                        className="list__item"
                        key={user.name}
                        onClick={() => this.selectRight(user.id)}
                      >
                        {user.name}
                        {`(${user.id})`}
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="modal__footer">
              <button onClick={this.closeModal}>Cancel</button>
              <button onClick={this.saveList}>Save</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Popup>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Modal;
```

Can someone please have a look and see what am I missing here? Also, it helps me if there is any better way to do this.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-select-w1mmv)

Note: Currently I didn't add any visual experience for the selected item. Once the user clicks on any item it'll be in selected and using `> or <` buttons user can move items.

Comment: @Raju Why do you think this might solve the problem?

Comment: @Raju If that were the issue, OP would get an error message about `this`.

Comment: @Raju. That's not solving. Also, I'm using ES6 arrow function. I think there is no need of bind

Comment: @Raju When declaring functions with the [class property syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance) they are automatically bound to `this`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've found what's causing this; a click on the save button calls the save function, which calls `setState`. Asynchronously however. You call `this.closeModal()` immediately after, which means the modal's state is reset to the old props, because the parent's state hasn't updated yet. To fix this, update the modal's state in `componentDidUpdate()`

Comment: @trixn thanks for the explanation. I thought this might be problem with this.

Comment: Or we can call the close modal function in callback.
save = (itemsLeft, itemsRight) => {
    this.setState({
      usersUn: itemsLeft,
      usersSel: itemsRight
    }, function(){ //Close modal here } );
  };

Comment: @Raviteja Look at my answer. I have created working demo for you.

Comment: Here's my take: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-select-eg0vo An `async` save functions allows waiting for the parent's state to change before updating the child's state (also, instead of shifting users around I keep arrays of IDs) (You also need to add `onClose={this.closeModal}` to your `<Popup>`, otherwise closing it by outside click will cause it to disappear and not reappear)

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks a lot for the demo. It's really helpful, but you spoiled all my enthusiasm by adding that extra functionality which I'm currently working on.  :(.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't mean to do that :/ Glad it still helps though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem come from the saveList function.

When you call `this.props.save` it will execute a `setState` in you `Sample` parent.

Has setState() is **asynchronous**, even you call closeModal with the props, the props are not updated with the 'good' values at this time.

Try to set `itemLefts` and `itemsRight` in the **openModal()** instead

```
openModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: true,
      itemsLeft: this.props.usersUn,
      itemsRight: this.props.usersSel
    });
  };

  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: false
    });
  };
```

Comment: Your answer seems right. I want to know if there is any better way to handle this state. As I only want to update the state once the user clicks save and the last saved state if user cancels after moving items.

Comment: @Raviteja You need to use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method of the modal. Check if the open state changed to `false` and reset the state then.

Comment: @trixn can you please elaborate? I'm bit confused.

Comment: @trixn you mean this `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.open !== this.state.open) {
      this.setState({
        itemsLeft: this.props.usersUn,
        itemsRight: this.props.usersSel
      });
    }
  }`

Comment: @Raviteja You could conditionally reset the modal state if you detect that the modal has been closed. This would need to be done in `componentDidUpdate`. However the solution proposed to reset it when opening is totally fine and leads to the same behaviour.

Comment: @trixn can you please check my above comment?

Comment: @Raviteja Yes that seems correct at first sight. But you can also just stick to the solution proposed to reset it in `openModal`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your `saveList` method. `this.closeModal();` line will reset your value. So you have to just update the `open` state only.
Please update it as below.

```
  saveList = () => {
    this.props.save(this.state.itemsLeft, this.state.itemsRight);
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };
```

Here is the working demo for you https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-select-olqc9.

Comment: But it might not take effect. We should call the close modal somewhere in setState() callback. What do you think?
save = (itemsLeft, itemsRight) => { this.setState({ usersUn: itemsLeft, usersSel: itemsRight }, function(){ //Close modal here } ); }

Comment: but `closeModal` is reset your state based on given props.

Comment: I have created demo for you https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-select-olqc9

Comment: Your answer is also helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I have noticed couple of issues in your demo. I guess you are still working on it.

Comment: @ClueMediator issues like? If it's visual experience, I'm working on it.

Comment: If you click multiple times on the same item at left side and then click on button `>` then it will add multiple records at right side.

Answer (score 1):

State updates are asynchronous. When pressing save you update the parent state with the current values but then also update the modal state with what you got passed via props which **still is the old state**.